# What are the implications of gorilla anatomy on medieval warfare?

Tags: technology, medieval, culture, anatomy, materials

Let me know if I need to break this into smaller questions...my preference is to keep it as one.

I have a sentient species that has intelligence indistinguishable from humans, but with the body of a gorilla. Their anatomy can be considered identical to that of gorillas with the following slight modifications:

1. Fully opposable thumbs
2. More complex vocal apparatus (so they have more sounds and access to language)

This species has progressed technologically to an age similar to medieval times* on a planet similar to Earth. They have religion and laws and politics and a patriarchal culture. They are the dominant species on their planet and they don’t know of any other sentient species (they’ve never heard of humans or aliens).

**My question:
What would the implications of ape physiology and anatomy be on medieval warfare? How would it be different from medieval warfare as we knew it on Earth?**

Some of the most important differences in gorilla anatomy:

- fully grown silverbacks are stronger than 20 adult humans combined. Can bench press 4,000 lbs…let that sink in
- their arms are both longer and stronger than their legs (instead of vice-versa for humans) but note that they are too heavy for brachiating
- can sprint up to 20-25mph (for reference…average human athlete: 15mph. average horse speed: 30 mph)
- they *cannot* run for long distances; no marathons
- they can’t jump high, but if they get a running start they can make jumps up to 25 feet in length
- their anatomy makes throwing things possible, but laughably inaccurate compared to humans
- they are vegetarians
- much more powerful jaws
- opposable toes
- long coarse body hair

**What implications do you see?**

Note: I didn't talk about the differences socially between gorillas and humans. That's not because I'm assuming it doesn't matter; it's just that I'm unsure where to begin there.

*More details on spelling out what medieval technology means to me: they have farming, and feudal systems, they have animal husbandry with a variety of work animals as well as horse-like animals for transportation. They have the ability to make castles and plate mail and crossbows and trebuchets, etc. They have writing and sophisticated wooden ships and navigation items like the sextant. They do NOT have gunpowder or the printing press.

Comment: "what implications" would seem to be broad and open-ended. Do you have a specific problem that needs solving?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. the problem that I want to solve is...I want to know the implications...so that I can craft a good, coherent storyverse. I don't have a problem more specific than that.

Comment: [Fishing for ideas](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7304/where-do-i-go-if-im-just-fishing-for-ideas) are a better fit for chat than worldbuilding main. Please narrow the question to a single clearly defined worldbuilding issue that needs to be tackled - which should be well enough constrained to identify a single "best answer".

Comment: VTC (a) This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) that violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule. I.E., the question is too broad. An entire book could be written on the impact of gorilla physiology on medieval warfare (where do we stop? Forest warefare? Coastal? Naval? Impact on cavalry? Value of chainmail with/for/against...? Impact on cities... trade... society... all that's part of "medieval warfare.") We are more than willing to help you resolve specific questions.

Comment: So, this is an interesting concept. In the vein of Planet of the Apes. I think your first instinct was correct: this really would work better broken down into a number of distinct queries. You've got ten bullet points, and each of those could literally be answered by a whole chapter, which means the answer you're looking for is an actual book!  +1 for being a cool underlying concept that you are approaching rationally; but VTC for asking too many questions at once!

Comment: *"Their anatomy makes throwing things [...] laughably inaccurate":* What exactly in their anatomy is making their hand-eye coordination so bad?

Comment: *"Fully opposable thumbs"* .. So tell me, in what world do gorillas not already have fully opposable thumbs? because it's not this real one I'm sitting in right now.

Comment: @Pelinore second paragraph of this article explains it well. They don't have full "precision grip" capabilities. https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.96.1.313#:~:text=Within%20nonhuman%20primates%2C%20great%20apes,more%20finger%20tips%20(1).

Comment: @AlexP it's not hand-eye coordination, but the fact that they don't walk upright and don't have the same shoulder configuration we do https://www.yeovilorthoclinic.co.uk/why-gorillas-cant-throw/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, all. I'll start forming and posting more specific questions one at a time. Is it better to just leave this question here as is (closed), or to delete it altogether?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of implications to do with their physiology and nutrition.

Gorillas spend half the day eating, they have no choice, they need to fuel their huge bodies. Yet you don't see fat gorillas, that food all gets used up.

They sleep for 12 hours and more

By choice they don't travel more than a mile a day

The males weigh around 170kg (poor horses)

They're knuckle walkers, so their hands and wrists are made to withstand forces due to that that we don't and they can't carry much very far.

They don't have fat reserves like humans, so they cannot withstand privation for long.

Large groups of gorillas are rare, usually a dominant male with a friend or two and a bunch of females and adolescents. More silverbacks causes fights because they're all competing for females.

They have a very sedentary lifestyle (humans are the most active of the great apes), so getting them building castles and stuff is a bit much to ask. Or doing anything much really. I doubt you could keep an army of them in the field long.

Comment: Lots of good points, but would be better if you could take the analysis to the next step for many of them:  1. Weight means riding horses is out, fight from chariots (as ancient humans did until they bred horses large and strong enough for a rider.  2. Inability to travel long distances on foot mean troop transport relies on wagons pulled by beasts of burden.  3.  High food requirement means armies need lots of wagons for supplies.  4. Combine 2 and 3 and gorilla armies will be smaller due to massive transport requirements.  5. No long sieges as cannot continue once insufficient food.  Etc

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 could have gone on forever but there's no point. Intelligent gorillas could not get to medieval level. Their biology constrains them. While our inferior in many respects biology makes it almost inevitable.

Comment: @Kilisi: Our biology is not "inferior", it is just optimized for a different lifestyle. Humans are optimized for endurance -- generating moderate mechanical power for a long time. The other great apes are optimized for short intense bursts of power. Our muscles are not "weak" -- they are as strong as possible while still allowing the lungs and circulatory system to keep them working in aerobic mode for hours and hours. Before humans were human they were a very successful savannah great ape.

Comment: @AlexP I said 'inferior in many respects'.... there's a difference from what you mean. You're correct though. No argument from me on that. The point is that the gorillas optimisations preclude it from being sucessful at our lifestyle.

Answer (score 1):

### No way

Gorillas cannot develop a civilization without losing their gorilla-ness and becoming funny-looking humans.

Humans are not "weak" great apes; we are great apes optimized for endurance. Our muscles are not "weak"; they are as strong as possible while still allowing the lungs and the heart to supply them with sufficient oxygen to work in aerobic mode for hours and hours.

Before humans were humans we were pretty successful savannah great apes. As they meme goes, *we hunted the mammoth*. No other great ape can do what humans can do; of course the reverse is also true -- we cannot do what other great apes can do. A gorilla will outrun a human over very short distances; but on medium and long distances the human will outrun the gorilla easily. (Fun fact: the only animal which is a better runner than humans in any race in any conditions is the ostrich. Over long distances, horses can beat us only if the conditions are favorable to them.)

A human smithy can wield a 6 kg (12 pounds) sledgehammer for hours. A gorilla can indeed wield a 30 kg (60 pounds) sledgehammer -- for two or three minutes; then the gorilla must stop working, because once the oxygen reserves stored locally in the muscles are gone, they are gone and need time to be replenished.

Civilisation means *work*. Long hours of work, focused on the task at hand. Gorillas cannot do that, unless they shed their useless biggg muscles and reduce the weight of their bones accordingly.

Oh, and they must make their legs longer. Gorillas can and do walk on two legs, just like us, but for them this is only an occasional and rather inefficient mode of locomotion. To develop a civilization they must abandon knuckle walking so that they can keep their hands free to carry things; and must lengthen their legs so that bipedal locomotion becomes reasonably efficient.

And then what you get is just a funny looking human, with maybe somewhat shorter legs and longer arms.

Answer (score 0):

Implications I have concluded so far:

- Throwing spears or rocks with any precision is out
- Due to their upper body strength, they would probably be better at battering rams as a way of breaking into castles
- They can sprint almost as fast as horses so, while cavalry charges would still be a little more effective, charging on foot would be decently effective as well
- Alternatively, maybe a handful of shock troops could be like human (er, gorilla) cannonballs: they get running starts and then make large jumps into enemy lines, breaking up formations and allowing the regular troops who follow them to have entry points for attack
- Horses would also be useful for their endurance. They can gallop 1-2 miles without a break, and 50-100 miles per day if it’s a good endurance horse.
- Because they’re so strong, they could carry really thick armor…they could also have even beefier crossbows and longbows though…which would win out though I don’t know.*

*Research so far on the topic: apparently in human medieval warfare, good crossbows and longbows were apparently able to pierce “normal” plate armor, although rich people would have fancier plate armor that was much harder to pierce.  What I don’t know is, would gorillas’ increased strength have a bigger impact on their defense (through wearing thicker armor) or offense (through having crossbows/longbows that take a stronger person to draw and thicker arrows/bolts)

Comment: It's pretty much always possible to draw a heavier crossbow, it will just take more time.

Comment: For reference see: [wind-up medieval crossbow](https://crossbowweaponofchoice.blogspot.com/2012/03/crossbow-terminology-crossbow-is-called.html) - a more powerful crossbow just takes more winding, it's in the gearing.